# grep outputs differently for pip list vs pip list -o

Tags: regex, grep, pip

I know there are various ways to update outdated packages using pip, which is what I was attempting to do here.  However, my question is about the different outputs given by this expression depending on whether I use `pip list` or `pip list -o`. I'm trying to match just the package name itself.

```
$ pip list | grep -o '^.*\ '
arrow
backports.ssl-match-hostname
bsddb3
bzr
chardet
...
```

contrasting with:

```
$ pip list --outdated| grep -o '^.*\ '
chardet (Current: 2.0.1 Latest:
crypto (Current: 1.0.0 Latest:
fastimport (Current: 0.9.2 Latest:
feedparser (Current: 5.0.1 Latest:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the pattern is `.*` because the `.` tries to match anything including space where as we intent not to include space. A little change in the pattern can do the work

```
$ pip2 list --outdated | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

Here rather than trying to match anything, `.*` we attempt to match anything other than a space `[^ ]*`

**What it does?**

- `^` anchors the regex at the starting of string
- `[^ ]*` matches anything other than space, `*` quantifies it

**Test**

```
$ pip2 list --outdated | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
reportlab
numpy
requests
pyparsing
google-api-python-client
pytz
PyMetis
Django
httplib2
```

**OR**

You can use a non greedy matching as

```
$ pip list | grep -o '^.*?\ '
```

Comment: I see. So the expression I used matched everything up to the _last_ space, rather than the first one, is that right?  I had assumed that it would match the first space.  Is that a default?

Comment: @pak `.*` is greedy and attempts to match till the last space. You can also use a non greedy matching like `.*?` I have added that to answer